# How do I turn off active tabs in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

My tabs work great, but I can't figure out how to turn them off when I click that same tab again. As you can see I can hover over the tabs and click on them but I can't reclick to turn them off.

Bonus idea -  I'd also like to be able to hover over them and have the information preview!!

app.js -

```
app.controller("TabController", function() {
    this.tab = 0;

    this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
      return this.tab === checkTab;
    };

    this.setTab = function(setTab) {
      this.tab = setTab;
    };
  });
```

index.html -

```
<span class="pull-right" ng-controller="TabController as tab">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(1) }">
              <a href="" ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">News</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(2) }">
              <a href="" ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Scores</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(3) }">
              <a href="" ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Alternate Sites</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <div ng-show="tab.isSet(1)">
            {{site.news}}
          </div>

          <div ng-show="tab.isSet(2)">
            <blockquote>Governance - {{site.goverance}} | Environment - {{site.environment}} | Community - {{site.community}}</blockquote>
            Powered by CSRhub
          </div>

          <div ng-show="tab.isSet(3)">
            <section ng-show="site.alternatives.length">
              <ul class="list-inline thumbs">{{site.alternatives}}</ul>
            </section>
          </div>
        </span>
        </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want to do is this:

```
app.controller("TabController", function() {
    this.tab = 0;

    this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
      return this.tab === checkTab;
    };

    this.setTab = function(setTab) {
      if(setTab==this.tab)
          this.tab=-1
      else
          this.tab = setTab;
    };
  });
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Any idea about how to get mouseover or hover to display the contents using AngularJS?

Comment: @user3709592 I'm not sure what you mean by that, not sure how you pretend to display it or where... So if you want you could start another question.